# Theorem 11.2 in Matsumura

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

I have a question about the proof of $(4) \implies (3)$ in Theorem 11.2 of Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory*.

[image]

The setup is as follows. Let $R$ be a normal Noetherian local ring of dimension $1$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Choose $x\in\mathfrak{m}\setminus\mathfrak{m}^2$.
Matsumura now says:

> Since $\dim R=1$ the only prime ideals of $R$ are $(0)$ and $\mathfrak{m}$, so that $\mathfrak{m}$ must be a prime divisor of $xR$, and  **there exists $y\in R$ such that $(xR:y)=\mathfrak{m}$**.

Why is the last statement true?

Comment: In the quoted sentence, what does it mean that “$\mathfrak{m}$ is a prime divisor of $xR$”? I guess it might have to do with primary decomposition? A search for “prime divisor of an ideal” on google doesn't give anything.

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo a "prime divisor of an ideal" = a prime ideal containing that ideal, just like for integers: p is a divisor of n iff $(n) \subseteq (p)$. Sometimes people also write "associated prime divisors" for associated primes, and just drop the "associated". In the geometric context, the notion of divisor usually also includes being codim 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because  $\;\mathfrak m/xR$ is in $\operatorname{Ass}(R/xR)$ – actually it is the sole element of  $\operatorname{Ass}(R/xR)$.

Comment: Aha—$R/xR$ has the unique prime ideal $\mathfrak{m}/xR$, so this must be an associated prime ideal of $R/xR$. Hence there exists some $\overline{y}$ such that $\mathfrak{m}/xR=\operatorname{ann}(\overline{y})$, i.e. $\mathfrak{m}=(xR:y)$.

Comment: $\def\frm{\mathfrak{m}}
\def\frp{\mathfrak{p}}$For those who are reading about associated primes for the first time (like me) to understand this: one has to use that if $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $M$ is an $R$-module, then $M\neq 0$ iff $\operatorname{Ass}M\neq\varnothing$ (cf. Matsumura's *Commutative Algebra*, Corollary 7.1; alternatively, [Tag 0587](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0587)). Thus, the unique prime of $R/xR$ (namely, $\mathfrak{m}/xR$) must equal $\operatorname{Ass}(R/xR)$.